# Could tensorflow dynamically add file into the FIFOQueue in training

Tags: tensorflow

I have tested the code like this:

```
    # filename_queue comes from tf.train.string_input_producer
    features, labels, filename_queue = read_batch_data(file_list, 10)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        sess.run(init)
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
        counter = 0
        try:
            while not coord.should_stop():
                counter = counter + 1
                value = features.eval()
                if counter % 1000 == 0:
                    # check whether new data has been inserted into the queue
                    print counter, sum(value)
                    index = (counter / 1000) % 3
                    enqueue_op = filename_queue.enqueue(['a%d.csv' % index])
                    sess.run([enqueue_op])
         except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError
             ...
```

But looks the graph still use the original file queue, and never read the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have a large prefetched buffer with old set of names so when you add a new filename, it's only going to be seen after the prefetched buffer is exhausted. By default `tf.string_input_producer` will keep cycling infinitely through the set of names, and it will fill up the prefetching buffer of size `32`.

If you want to modify the list it's easier to use a `FIFOQueue` and fill it with examples manually instead of `string_input_producer.` Be careful of not feeding enough examples and hanging your main thread, may want to set `config.operation_timeout_in_ms=5000` for your session

For instance, the following example entries from /temp/pipeline/0 file once (there are 10 entries in the file), after which it will print entries from /temp/pipeline/1

Create some test data

```py
def dump_numbers_to_file(fname, start_num, end_num):
  with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(start_num, end_num):
      f.write(str(i)+"\n")
num_files=10
num_entries_per_file=10
file_root="/temp/pipeline"
os.system('mkdir -p '+file_root)
for fi in range(num_files):
  fname = file_root+"/"+str(fi)
  dump_numbers_to_file(fname, fi*num_entries_per_file, (fi+1)*num_entries_per_file)
```

Helper utility to create session

```py
def create_session():
  """Resets local session, returns new InteractiveSession"""
  config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
  config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3 # don't hog all vRAM
  config.operation_timeout_in_ms=15000   # terminate on long hangs
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession("", config=config)
  return sess
```

Run your example

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()
filename_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=10, dtypes=[tf.string])
enqueue_op = filename_queue.enqueue("/temp/pipeline/0")
sess = create_session()
sess.run(enqueue_op)
sess.run(enqueue_op)
# filename queue now has [/temp/pipeline/0, /temp/pipeline/0]
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
numeric_val, = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=[[-1]])
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

for i in range(10):
  print sess.run([numeric_val])

# filename queue now has [/temp/pipeline/0]
print 'size before', sess.run(filename_queue.size())
sess.run(filename_queue.enqueue("/temp/pipeline/1"))

# filename queue now has [/temp/pipeline/0, /temp/pipeline/1]
print 'size after', sess.run(filename_queue.size())

for i in range(10):
  print sess.run([numeric_val])

# filename queue now has [/temp/pipeline/1]

for i in range(10):
  print sess.run([numeric_val])

# filename queue is now empty, next sess.run([numeric_val]) would hang

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

You should see

```
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
size before 1
size after 2
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
[10]
[11]
[12]
[13]
[14]
[15]
[16]
[17]
[18]
[19]
```

Comment: Good answer. But, It looks like it will block the data pipeline when you execute enqueue op. Or, will it just trigger the queue threads?